Elasticsearch: Highlighting issue with fuzzy query with edge_ngram tokens
I couldn’t find a relevant example, so here’s my issue:
I’m developing a search-as-you-type feature using edge_ngram tokens, which allows for spelling mistakes (fuzzy queries) while highlighting the current edge_ngram token being matched.
The problem arises with exact matches: the highlight appears one character ahead due to the fuzzy component. For example, with a field value of “37751” and a query of “3775”, the highlight shows “37751” because of the fuzziness. The fuzzy query seems to prioritize the resulting longer token, causing it to be highlighted.
I’ve tried adjusting the highlights parameter, specifically setting the fragment_size to the length of the query, but the issue persists.
Can you help me resolve this?
For reproducibility, here are my mappings, settings, and query. Thanks in advance.
Settings
   {"index": {"max_ngram_diff": 10},
    "analysis": {

        "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
            },
            "autocomplete_search": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type": "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 10,
                "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"],
            },
        },
    }

Mappings
{
    "properties": {
        "A_ID": {"type": "text", "copy_to": "autocomplete_text"},
        "B_ID": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "autocomplete_text",
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "autocomplete_text",
        },
        "autocomplete_text": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        },
    }
}

Query
query= "3775"
 
bool = {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "autocomplete_text": {
                        "query": query,
                        "operator": "and",
                        "boost": 10,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "autocomplete_text": {
                        "query": query,
                        "operator": "and",
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    }
                },
            },
        ],
    }
}
 
highlight = {
    "fields": [
        {
            "autocomplete_text": {
                "fragment_size": len(query),
            }
        }
    ],
}


TL;DR: The simplest way to achieve your goal is to forgo Elasticsearch's highlighting and instead find the matches for highlighting yourself based on your own rules.
The issue lies in how "fuzziness" is defined in Elasticsearch. Two tokens are considered matching if the Levenshtein distance between the token in your query and the token, in the results is less or equal to the value specified in your query. If you set fuzziness to auto, then in your example with a token length of 4, the distance should be less than or equal to 1.
The distance is calculated as the minimum number of characters that you need to add, delete, change, or optionally transpose in one token to get another token. All operations have the same weight - 1. You cannot specify which operations are allowed, except for the optional transpose operation that can be disabled using the fuzzy_transpositions flag.
From a fuzziness perspective, Elasticsearch treats the distance between abcd and abcdX the same as the distance between abcd and abXcd or abcX and abcY, and there are no settings to change this behavior at the moment. From a highlighting perspective, the highlight function relies on the tokens provided by the query to determine what to highlight and if token was created by addition at the end of deletion in the middle.
To summarize, as far as I know there are no built-in settings at the moment that can be applied to tweak the behavior the way you want it to be tweaked (don't allow addition at the end of the word when calculating fuzziness) in fuzziness and highlighting.

meaning the client handling this ?

So far, the only solutions I have found are:

Send two queries (one with fuzziness and one without) and then combine the results.
Switch the tokenizer to n_gram and eliminate the need for fuzziness.


I meant whatever app is calling elasticsearch should perform highlighting. However, if 1. works for you, you can do it in a single request by overriding query for highlighter - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html#specify-highlight-query I didn't suggest that because it will not handle any misspellings, so I didn't think it is acceptable. Regarding 2. fine-tuning highlighting with n-gram is not for the faint-hearted, but if you found something that works acceptably well and indexing performance is acceptable, it's great.
